# A working Drag&Drop enabled ListView implementation for WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, controls

Been trying to find a working implementation of a WPF listview (or listbox) where
you can order items by dragging them up or down.

I have found a few, but none really works,
for example this one
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ListViewDragDropManager.aspx?msg=2765618#xx2765618xx
stops working once you have list where you need to scroll down to get to the last items.

Why is Drag&Drop so hard in WPF?
Does anybody know a working control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag&Drop is not SO hard, really :)

Try reading this [post](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=53) about Drag&Drop.

Comment: Link's broken, domain is parked; looks like the post you're referring to moved [here](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488).

Comment: That link is also broken

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDragDrop.aspx) article on CodeProject!

It is not as full featured as Josh & Bea's implementation but it is very simple to use...

This implementation rely on attached properties (Attached behaviour)

Source

```
<ListBox src:DragAndDrop.DragEnabled="true"/>
```

Target

```
<ListBox src:DragAndDrop.DropEnabled="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with WPF drag and drop for a while now and decided to just bite the bullet and create a framework for it.

You can find the code here: http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/

I’d love to get some feedback on this, hopefully it will solve your problem!

Comment: I will take a look at it... but it might take some time, thank you